# How to pass character array to a function in C++ without any temporary char array as variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, string-literals

I have the following code

```
void func(char c[])  {
    c[1]= '@';
    std::cout<<c<<"\n"
             <<sizeof(c)<<"\n";
}

// Main 1
int main()  {
    char temp[6] = "pinta";
    func(temp);
}
```

Here if I change the main function to the following

```
//Main 2
int main()
{
    func("pinta");
}

meow@vikkyhacks ~/Arena/c/LinkedList $ g++-4.8 scrap/test.cpp 
scrap/test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
scrap/test.cpp:12:14: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
  func("pinta");
              ^
```

After some googling, I learned that the second `main` is not passing any character array by instead passing a `read only string literal` which when hits the `c[1] = '@'` throws a seg fault.

My Question is

1. "***How do I avoid the use of the `temp` variable which is used in
   the `Main 1` and directly pass a character array to the `func` as
   its parameter ?***"
2. And important condition is to allow the editing of the character
   array passed into the `func`.

### EDIT

I see there are many answers which prevent me from doing `c[1]= '@';` , which I cannot do because that line is very important for me.

Comment: "classic" C arrays cannot be passed by value (unless encapsulated in a struct). Use std::string.

Comment: Change this `void func(char c[])` to `void func(const char* c, size_t c_size)` and do everything consistently!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ After doing that, how will I able to change `c[1]` to `@`, the line `c[1] = '@'` will hit an error.

Comment: @vikkyhacks _'how will I able to change ...'_ You cannot, that's all of the point!

Comment: You can't do what you want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot avoid creating a temporary, because it's illegal to write to the memory of a string literal, but you can make the compiler create it for you. Take as your parameter `std::string` instead- this is much safer than `char` arrays and will create a copy for you.

Comment: @vikkyhacks He just told you what to do. You should also change sizeof(c) to c.size() in that case also.

Comment: @rightfold `func("")` ... enjoy . (just a comment on the string panacea)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is this :

```
template<int N>
void func(char const (&c)[N])  
{
    // c[1] = '@'; you cannot assign to variable that is const
    std::cout << c << "\n"
        << sizeof(c) << "\n";
}


int main()
{
    func("pinta");  
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that you only bind temporaries to const references.

Above you are actually passing a reference to an array sized as much as the length + 1(=`\0`) of the string literal you are giving.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/4xRKFB)

---

If you need a modifiable variable inside `func`, then you need a copy of the `char` array :

```
template<int N>
void func(char const (&c)[N])  
{
    char cp[N];
    copy(begin(c), end(c), cp); 
    auto len = distance(begin(cp), end(cp));

    if (len > 1) cp[1] = '@';
    std::cout << cp << "\n"
        << sizeof(cp) << "\n";
}
```

I'd also add some range checking (it's the `len` part)